# JQuery Path location

Tags: asp.net, jquery

am using Asp.Net C# 2.0. My website is working fine in local. Website contains 2 js files included in master page.  It works fine in local environment, but when i publish my website i get "Object expected" error on page load, and thus the js functions are not working in published website.

Currently I am writing:

```
 <script src="/javascripts/jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the master page.

Looking forward for help.

Comment: @kemi show us the code how you are adding javsacript files, are you giving relative path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ResolveUrl method like this:

```
<script src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/javascripts/jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are direcories in your application. Example:
ROOT
  foldera
    file1.aspx
  file2.aspx
  masterpage

assuming file1.aspx and file2.aspx use masterpage, your js link will be rendered different.
file1.aspx will look for the js in:
ROOT/foldera/javascripts/jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.js
file2.aspx will look for the js in:
ROOT/javascripts/jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.js

in order to solve this you have several options:
1. use ResolveUrl as Fasih Hansmukh suggested.
2. put the script under ScriptManager tag:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/javascripts/jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I attach the jscript on the master page programatically,

```
AppendScript("/javascripts/jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.js");

private void AppendScript(string jsURL)
{
    HtmlGenericControl myJs = new HtmlGenericControl();

    myJs.TagName = "script";
    myJs.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
    myJs.Attributes.Add("src", HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath + (jsURL.Substring(0, 1) != "/" ? "/" + jsURL : jsURL));
    this.Header.Controls.Add(myJs);
}
```